# Initialising a vector of struct in a constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, struct

I have no idea on how to initialise a vector of struct within a constructor. Anyone can give me pointers? ^^

This is my struct:

```
struct Point {
int x;
int y;
};
```

This is my header file:

```
class ShapeTwoD {
private:
string name;
bool containsWarpSpace;
vector<Point> vertices;
public:    
ShapeTwoD();
ShapeTwoD(string,bool,vector<Point>);

virtual string getName();
virtual bool getContainsWarpSpace();
virtual string toString();

vector<Point> points;

virtual double computeArea() = 0;
virtual bool isPointInShape(int,int) = 0;
virtual bool isPointonShape(int,int) = 0;

virtual void setName(string);
virtual void setContainsWarpSpace(bool);
};
```

This is my .cpp file:

```
ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD() {
name = "";
containsWarpSpace = true;
vertices = "";
}

ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD(string name, bool containsWarpSpace,vector<Point>vertices) {
this->name = name;
this->containsWarpSpace = containsWarpSpace;
this->vertices = vertices;
}
```

It gives me this error:

> ShapeTwoD.cpp:12: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((ShapeTwoD*)this)->ShapeTwoD::vertices = ""’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:156: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = Point, _Alloc = std::allocator]

Comment: Please read a textbook. Thank you.

Comment: Please test your own code and ask only if you found actual problems with it - the comment in the last .cpp file suggests that you have not tried running it.

Comment: The way you are initializing things in your constructor is broken. Read your book, it will explain why.

Comment: @UnholySheep I could only think of putting `vertices = ""` and `= 0`. Same error

Comment: As the error tells you, you cannot use `vertices = ""` it is not defined. What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing that? The vector itself already exists (and is empty), if you want to add a single element try using `vertices.push_back("");` which will add an empty string element to the vector

Comment: @UnholySheep Ok thanks i understand now. You mind putting up an ans and i will vote urs. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:
The error message states that there is no definition for `vertices = ""`. The vector however already exists (and is empty) and therefore must not be initialised.
Appending an empty string to the vector can be done through `vertices.push_back("");` if necessary

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to initialize the vector to be empty.

The compiler will create an empty vector for you, so you don't need to.

The numbers and booleans in your ShapeTwoD instances *should* be initialized to sensible defaults, as with the `containsWarpSapce` variable.

```
ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD() 
  containsWarpSpace = true;
}
```

You can use an initializer list instead.  It's not critical for this example, but a good practice if your objects non-trivial types.

```
// Preferred: use initializer list.
ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD() 
:  containsWarpSpace(true)
{}
```